I don't understand why the Django built in 'Reverse' function is not working
I am trying to learn Django in python, when today, I stumbled upon this error:
"NoReverseMatch at /downloader/
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name."
I am not sure why this is happening, but here is my code:
(this is the views.py code)
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("login"))

(here is my urls.py)
urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("add/", views.add, name="add"),
path('scrape/', views.scrape_all, name='scrape_all'),
path('find_url/', views.find_song_urls, name='find_song_urls'),
path('downloader/', views.downloader, name="downloader"),
path("login/", views.login_view, name="login"),
path("logout/", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
path("create_acount/", views.create_account, name="create_account")
]

I was just trying to make a login function with my project but I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Did you SAVE the urls.py file after editing it?

yes I did, I saved it

Is this urls.py in main app (near settings) or in app urls.py?

The urls.py I am talking about here is in the app, it is not in the project near the settings

theen try using reverse("app_name:login")

Yeah it worked, thank you very much. I am just new to this so it is hard for me to understand

Sooo question was solved. If anyone seeks for same answer:
For shortcuts like reverse() or reverse_lazy() Django needs url name and also your app name.
Pattern is "app_name:url_name"

If you set an app_name [Django-doc] in the urls module, or you explicitly set a namespace, you need to prefix the name with that app name, so my_app_name:login in this case.
You can make use of redirect(…) [Django-doc] instead of first calling reverse(…) [Django-doc] and then wrap it in a HttpResponseRedirect object [Django-doc]. The redirect(…) function does not only offer a more convenient signature to do this, it also for example will use the .get_absolute_url() method [Django-doc] if you pass it a model object, so:
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('app_name:login')
That being said, redirecting in case the user did not login is a very common use-case, that has been encapsulated in the @login_required decorator [Django-doc], we can thus use:
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def my_view(request):
    # …
    pass
in the settings.py, we can then set the LOGIN_URL setting [Django-doc] to specify to what view we should redirect:
# settings.py

# …

LOGIN_URL = 'app_name:login'
